# Erro na lógica de recursividade

Tags: c, recursão

Minha função recursiva precisa calcular a potência de b elevado a N está dando erro de "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)", o que pode ser?

Minha função:

```
int potencia(int b, int n, int a){

if(n == 0){
    return b;
}

    b=b*a;

    return potencia(b,n-1,a);
}

int main(){
    int a,b,pot,n;

    printf("Informe um valor b: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Informe um valor expo: ");
    scanf("%d",&expo);

    a=b;
    pot=potencia(b,expo,a);
    printf("%d\n",pot);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vi esse erro agora e corrigir, mas quando fui testar colocando b=2 e expo=3, deu 16 o resultado, era pra ter dado 8, o q pode ter sido?

Comment: Um número elevado a 1 é igual a ele mesmo. Troque o teste n = 0 pra n = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, sua função não precisa de 3 parâmetros. Se você quer calcular "b elevado a n", precisa somente de dois parâmetros (`b` e `n`).

Agora vamos verificar como deve ser a função `potencia`.
Pensando em exponenciação de maneira recursiva, usando como exemplo 2 ao cubo:

- **2<sup>3</sup>** é o mesmo que **2 * 2<sup>2</sup>**
- **2<sup>2</sup>** é o mesmo que **2 * 2<sup>1</sup>**
- **2<sup>1</sup>** é o mesmo que **2 * 2<sup>0</sup>**
- **2<sup>0</sup>** é igual a 1

Ou seja, de maneira genérica, temos que:

- **2<sup>n</sup>** é o mesmo que **2 * 2<sup>n - 1</sup>**
- mas se `n` for zero, o resultado é 1

Portanto, sua função deve usar estas regras:

```
// b elevado a n
int potencia(int b, int n){
    // se n for zero, o resultado é 1
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    // b vezes (b elevado a n-1)
    return b * potencia(b, n-1);
}
```

E no `main`:

```
int main(){
    int b = 2;
    int expo = 3;
 
    int pot = potencia(b, expo);
    printf("%d\n", pot);
 
    return 0;
}
```

O resultado é 8.

---

Veja este código funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/oEWwTT).

Vale lembrar que usar recursão para este problema não é a melhor solução. O melhor seria fazer um loop simples para multiplicar o número várias vezes (e se for uma aplicação real e não um exercício, o ideal mesmo é usar [o que já tem pronto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)).

Comment: Entendi, obrigado amigo